# how to use core file in radare2?

Tags: radare2

In gdb i can backtrace with core file and executable file.
It seems radare2 can read core file. like this

```
$ r2 core
Setting up coredump: asm.arch <-> x86 and asm.bits <-> 64
Setting up coredump: Registers have been set
Setting up coredump: 22 maps have been found and created
[0x00000000]>
```

but after that i don't know what to do next?
I can't find any documentation about using core file in radare2.

Answer (score 1):

It's more regular programming question than RE. Core dump file is a state of the process when the file was created (usually due to a crash) so debugger commands are the most suitable in such case. In Radare2 those are the ones from `d?` category.

```
Usage: d   # Debug commands
| db[?]                    Breakpoints commands
| dbt[?]                   Display backtrace based on dbg.btdepth and dbg.btalgo
| dc[?]                    Continue execution
| dd[?]                    File descriptors (!fd in r1)
| de[-sc] [perm] [rm] [e]  Debug with ESIL (see de?)
| dg <file>                Generate a core-file (WIP)
| dH [handler]             Transplant process to a new handler
| di[?]                    Show debugger backend information (See dh)
| dk[?]                    List, send, get, set, signal handlers of child
| dL[?]                    List or set debugger handler
| dm[?]                    Show memory maps
| do[?]                    Open process (reload, alias for 'oo')
| doo[args]                Reopen in debugger mode with args (alias for 'ood')
| dp[?]                    List, attach to process or thread id
| dr[?]                    Cpu registers
| ds[?]                    Step, over, source line
| dt[?]                    Display instruction traces (dtr=reset)
| dw <pid>                 Block prompt until pid dies
| dx[?]                    Inject and run code on target process (See gs)
```

You can get values of registers when coredump was created by issuing `dr` command or show the backtrace by one of the `dbt`.

> but after that i don't know what to do next?

What are the next steps are really dependent on your case - what you want to obtain from this dump.

> I can't find any documentation about using core file in radare2.

Probably this is not the most used function in r2 ;)